# xlsxWriter issue regarding exporting String as dates using python

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

I have a list that includes dates in the following format: 11/01/2019. This date i convert to string .When I export this list to Excel, The Excel sheet recognizes these string as date .Is there a way to make these dates recognizable by Excel as string using python?thank a lot.

| DateTable |
| --- |
| 11/01/2019 |
| 12/01/2019 |
| 13/01/2019 |

```
data.insert(0, {'Date':datetime.strptime(str(DateTable)[j]),'%d/%m/%Y').strftime('%d/%m/%Y')})
self.date.to_excel('date.xlsx', sheet_name = 'Sheet1', index=False, engine='xlsxwriter')
```

Comment: *Don't* store dates as strings. Dates aren't strings in Excel. Excel has an actual date type, stored as a decimal. How dates appear depends on the cell style. Store the actual date value and change the style instead. Check the [Working with Dates and Time](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_dates_and_time.html) page in the XlsxWriter docs

Comment: Besides, in Python **dates have no format**. They're binary types. Formats apply only when parsing strings into dates or formatting dates as strings for export or display.

Comment: To help understand what you are trying to do could you explain why you want the datetime values in the data frame to be exported to Excel as strings?

Comment: thank PanagiotisKanavos and jimcnamara your support.i have a system need to import the excel but no include the date format, so i need to change the date to string or text in excel using python for import  to the system.

Comment: @BenSO that system will still read the formatted text value. Although it's quite probable it will read the *date* value and no formatting will be necessary. Have you actually tried exporting proper dates? Did you encounter a problem? If so, fix *that* problem, don't introduce *another* one

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos , yes, how to convert the date to text? i try to use strptime and strftime , but not work becuase the excel will  recognize date format even if cast the column as string

Comment: @BenSO what does `DataTable[j]` contain anyway? Why are you formatting it to a string then back to a date, then to a string? If it's already a date you should format it directly. Otherwise you're just wasting CPU cycles trying to get back the original value

Comment: @BenSO **you don't have to convert the date to text**. Every application that imports Excel sheets knows how to handle dates. And even if it doesn't, when it reads the cell as text it will see the *formatted* date. The same way **you** do when you open an Excel sheet with dates

Comment: @BenSO again, have you tried importing a sheet with proper dates? Did you encounter a problem? Does the other application have a bug, or did you assume it can't work?

Comment: @BenSO to put it another way, the poor guy that has to import those strings with arbitrary formats instead of dates will really hate it, especially if they have to import files from multiple countries. Instead of just importing an Excel sheet you'll force them to inspect your files, try to determine the formats, convert them back to dates and add safeguards to ensure you never export dates in the wrong format. Even in your own company, the other system may be running on a server with a US locale, or a cloud server with US locale.

Comment: Hi @PanagiotisKanavos,DataTable[j] is the loop for store the date, you means i dont need to use strptime and strftime?could you show me the code please.And then i try to export the date when i delete the strptime and strftime, the excel will show the date column is the date format.thanks

Comment: @BenSO again, have you tried importing Excel files with proper dates? Did you encounter a problem? Or haven't you tried yet? You can specify the display date format easily when creating the ExcelWriter object. Applications that can read Excel files can also read dates or formatted text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand what's at stake read [The Spanish family wrongly accused of child pornography due to a mistake reading a date](https://english.elpais.com/spanish_news/2020-09-08/the-spanish-family-wrongly-accused-of-child-pornography-due-to-a-mistake-reading-a-date.html).

From the comments it looks like the real question is how to generate an Excel file that gets imported into another appplication. Don't convert dates to strings, *especially in this case*.

If you want to display dates in a certain way, specify the date display format when creating the `ExcelWriter` object:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter("pandas_datetime.xlsx",
                        engine='xlsxwriter',
                        datetime_format='dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss',
                        date_format='dd/mm/yyyy')
```

Excel files aren't text, and all libraries that can import Excel files can handle date values, or know to read the formatted text value of a number or date.

Applications can import Excel dates without problems. That's the one advantage Excel has over CSV files - numbers and dates are binary values, they don't need parsing and aren't affected by localization settings.

If an application has to work with text though, it's always possible that the wrong format will be used, eg because the machine's locale settings changed, because whoever generated the Excel sheet made a mistake, because the application has to import files from multiple other systems that use different formats.

**Explanation**

Dates in Python (and C#, Java, JavaScript, MySQL, PostgreSQL,....) have no format. They're binary types. Formats apply only when parsing strings into dates or formatting dates as strings for export or display.

Excel has a date type as well. Dates and numbers aren't stored as strings, they're stored as binary values. How they are displayed depends on the cell's number format. Dates are stored as an OADate decimal whose integer part is an offset from 1899-12-30 and fractional part is the time in a 24 hour period.

If you want to display dates in a specific format, specify it in the cell style.

The XlsxWriter docs explain how to do that in [Working with dates and time](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_dates_and_time.html). The examples actually use the format you want:

```
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('date_examples.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

# Widen column A for extra visibility.
worksheet.set_column('A:A', 30)

# A number to convert to a date.
number = 41333.5

# Write it as a number without formatting.
worksheet.write('A1', number)                # 41333.5

format2 = workbook.add_format({'num_format': 'dd/mm/yy'})
worksheet.write('A2', number, format2)       # 28/02/13

format3 = workbook.add_format({'num_format': 'mm/dd/yy'})
worksheet.write('A3', number, format3)       # 02/28/13
```

You don't have to convert the date to an OADate decimal though. You can store dates directly. XlsxWriter  :

> ... supports datetime objects of type datetime.datetime, datetime.date, datetime.time and datetime.timedelta.

The XlsxWriter docs show how to [work with dates in Pandas as well](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_pandas_datetime.html). It's even easier - just pass the desired format as a parameter:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, date

# Create a Pandas dataframe from some datetime data.
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date and time': [datetime(2015, 1, 1, 11, 30, 55),
                                     datetime(2015, 1, 2, 1,  20, 33),
                                     datetime(2015, 1, 3, 11, 10    ),
                                     datetime(2015, 1, 4, 16, 45, 35),
                                     datetime(2015, 1, 5, 12, 10, 15)],
                   'Dates only':    [date(2015, 2, 1),
                                     date(2015, 2, 2),
                                     date(2015, 2, 3),
                                     date(2015, 2, 4),
                                     date(2015, 2, 5)],
                   })

# Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine.
# Also set the default datetime and date formats.
writer = pd.ExcelWriter("pandas_datetime.xlsx",
                        engine='xlsxwriter',
                        datetime_format='dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss',
                        date_format='dd/mm/yyyy')

# Convert the dataframe to an XlsxWriter Excel object.
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')

...
# Close the Pandas Excel writer and output the Excel file.
writer.save()
```

Comment: Thank you very much Panagiotis Kanavos, sorry for taking the time to let me understand the structure of Excel and XlsxWriter, a question let me know more

Answer (score -1):

You need to set number format of the cell to "Plain Text", which is `{'num_format': '@'}`

```
workbook = Workbook("output.xlsx")
cell_format = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '@'})
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
worksheet.write(0, 0, "15/12/2021", cell_format)
workbook.close()
```

And with pandas:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter("output.xlsx")
df.to_excel(writer, 'Sheet1')
workbook = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']
cell_format = workbook.add_format({"num_format": "@"})
worksheet.set_column('A', 1, cell_format)
writer.save()
```

Comment: That's the exact opposite of what should be done. Excel has a date type. Dates should be stored as dates and the number format should be set to the desired date style

Comment: the question is "Is there a way to make these dates recognizable by Excel as string using pyhton"

Comment: Asking for the wrong thing doesn't mean the answer should also be wrong. What happens if you store `4/7/2021`? What date is this? You don't know and can't know. You may assume, but you don't know. You **will** read the wrong date sooner or later. This can lead not just to financial loss but could actually [get people arrested for no reason](https://english.elpais.com/spanish_news/2020-09-08/the-spanish-family-wrongly-accused-of-child-pornography-due-to-a-mistake-reading-a-date.html)

Comment: Worse, when that Excel sheet gets imported by another application, or read by someone in a different country, the strings will probably be misinterpreted, because again, the other app or user can't know what the intended format is.

Comment: thank @inf581, may i know how to implement the code to xlsxWriter lib? thanks

Comment: @BenSO don't do that. Read the docs. Writing the correct code is trivial. Using this bad answer is actually harder than doing it right

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the question is "Is there a way to make these dates recognizable by Excel as string using pyhton", and not "how to display dates in Excel in the exact format I want".

Comment: @inf581 to which the correct answer is `just set the correct format and Excel will provide the correct string`. Although the real question is in the comments - the file is meant to be imported into another application. In which case converting to text is **a really bad idea** and the poor IT guy that has to deal with that arbitrarily formatted strings will *really* hate it because it makes their life a *lot* harder

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos nope, those are two different questions with two different answers. Please excuse me for answering the question which is written by the author.

Comment: hi @inf581, thank for your advise, may i know how to implement "num_format": "@" to my code "self.date.to_excel('date.xlsx', sheet_name = 'Sheet1', index=False, engine='xlsxwriter')" thank so much

Comment: @BenSO please check the second part of my answer, your need to replace the line `df.to_excel...` with your `self.date.to_excel(writer, 'Sheet1', index=False)`

Comment: @BenSO and you need to update the range in excel in worksheet.set_column to apply the format